# Getting syntax error in discord.py cog

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm getting a syntax error when I try to load cog the error I get is

```
await self.bot.send_message(channel, content=":warning: @mods There is a possible raid in progress! :warning:")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this is what I'm working with

```js
import asyncio
import os
import discord
from datetime import datetime
from __main__ import send_cmd_help, settings
from discord.ext import commands
from .utils import checks
from .utils.dataIO import dataIO

class AntiRaid():
    """Alerts Staff about possible incoming raids"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.settings = dataIO.load_json("data/anti_raid/settings.json")

    async def on_member_join(self, member):    
      server = member.server
    if self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] is None:
        reset_time = 999 # a big number to trigger the timeout now
    else:
      last_reset = datetime.strptime(self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
      reset_time = (datetime.now() - last_reset).total_seconds()
      if reset_time > 30:
        self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = 0
        self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = str(datetime.now())
        dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
      if self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] < self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"]:
        self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] += 1
        dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
        return
      if (self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] >= self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"]) and reset_time <= 30:
        channel_id = self.settings[server.id]["channel"]
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await self.bot.send_message(channel, content=":warning: @everyone There is a possible raid happening! :warning:")
        self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = 0
        self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = str(datetime.now())
        dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
        return
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: I can't see an obvious syntax error there (apart from the inconsistent indentation, which is **very** important in Python). Are you sure the code you've posted is exactly the same as the code giving you a `SyntaxError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you have an `await` that is not in the body of a coroutine (an `async def` function).  Fix the indentation so that all the appropriate code is inside `on_member_join`.  As is, `on_member_join` is only one line long.